# Removing all but numbers and decimal points from a System::String

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a `System::String` (In C++ CLI windows forms application) which I want to format to remove all but numbers and decimal point.

The string should look like `"letters0.231 letters $#symbols"` and I would want to keep only `0.231`

I don't want to have to marshal this `String` into and `std::string` and use the `erase()` function, then have to convert back into a `System::String`

Is there a way to perform this operation on a `System::String` directly?

Comment: This is really a .NET question. You can use a System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex object to do this easily, or roll your own using System::Char::IsDigit() and IsLetter().

Comment: The CLI tag is for command line interface, the c++-cli tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a regular expression. Something as

```
String ^s = "letters0.231 letters $#symbols";
Regex ^regex = gcnew Regex( "\\d*\\.\\d*" );

s = regex->Match( s )->Value;
double d = Double::Parse( regex->Match( s )->Value );

Console::WriteLine( "s = {0}", s );
Console::WriteLine( "d = {0}", d );
```

Comment: @Cameron I am not strong with regular expressions. So i only pointed out the idea.:)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions could work, but for something like this, I'd take the direct approach: iterate the string, and put all the numbers and decimal points into a new string.

```
String^ GetNumbersAndDecimalPointOnly(String^ input)
{
    StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew StringBuilder(input->Length);

    for each (Char c in input)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        case '0':
        case '.':
            sb->Append(c);
            break;
        }
    }

    return sb->ToString();
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ input = "letters0.231 letters $#symbols";
    String^ output = GetNumbersAndDecimalPointOnly(input);

    Debug::WriteLine(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0.231
```

Just be sure to use capital-C `Char` in the for each loop. `Char` is `System::Char`, which is the wide, unicode character type. Lowercase-c `char` is a C++ char, which is the narrow, ASCII character type.

Also note that this isn't internationalized: Other countries use `,` for decimals, and there are digits in Unicode other than the 0-9 that are on your English keyboard.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Unicode; After all, _that's what System::String is._ There are **370 characters in the category DecimalDigitNumber.** However, System::Char is not really for characters; It's for UTF-16 code-units (one or two per character). Also, C++ char does not imply ASCII. It could very well hold a UTF-8 code-unit (one to four per character), an "ANSI code page" codepoint, or even an integer or binary data.